# Decode Firebase JWT in Python using PyJWT

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, pyjwt

I have written the following code :

```
def check_token(token):
    response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
    key_list = response.json()
    decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, key=key_list, algorithms=["RS256"])
    print(f"Decoded token : {decoded_token}")
```

I am trying to decode the `token` provided by firebase client side to verify it server-side.
The above code is throwing the following exception :

```
TypeError: Expecting a PEM-formatted key.
```

I have tried to not pass a list to the `jwt.decode` method, only the key content and i have a bigger error that the library `could not deserialize the Key`.
I was following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839874/how-to-decode-firebase-jwt-token-in-python) but i am getting this error.

Is it a `requests` conversion problem ? What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2nd parameter `key` in `decode()` seems to take a string value instead of list. The Google API request returns a dict/map containing multiple keys. The flow goes like:

1. Fetch public keys from the Google API endpoint
2. Then [read headers without validation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-headers-without-validation) to get the `kid` claim then use it to get appropriate key from that dict
3. That is a `X.509 Certificate` and not the public key as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54319965/13130697) so you need to get public key from that.

The following function worked for me:

```
import jwt
import requests
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography import x509

def check_token(token):
    n_decoded = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    kid_claim = n_decoded["kid"]

    response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
    x509_key = response.json()[kid_claim]
    key = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(x509_key.encode('utf-8'),  backend=default_backend())
    public_key = key.public_key()

    decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, public_key, ["RS256"], options=None, audience="<FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID>")
    print(f"Decoded token : {decoded_token}")

check_token("FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN")
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine ! What about the requested url, will developers be notified when this url changes ? I would not like a scenario where it would change and block all of the requests...

Comment: It shouldn't change (at least too frequently). I would expect a prior notice before it changes tbh but it'll be best to confirm with support @Tom3652

Comment: FYI the `backend` argument is ignored (kept in there for API compatibility), so you can omit it entirely.  (And avoid the hazmat API)